# How can I rotate the axis label in Julia plots?

Tags: julia

I'm trying to rotate the y axis label of a plot:

```
function contour(k::Real, a::Real = 6.0, y::Real = 12.0)
    y^2 / ((a^2) * k)
end

K_contour = range(0.5, stop = 8, length = 1000)

plot(K_contour, contour, xaxis = ("K", (0, 8)),
                         yaxis = ("L", (0,8)),
                         label = "", 
                         )
```

I get the following:[image]

I'd like to rotate the "L" 90 degrees. I can't find the appropriate axis attribute for this - can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [this julia forum answer](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/horizontal-y-label-with-plots-jl/9967/5) you need to use `pyplot` backend and `yguidefontrotation=-90` parameter:

```
pyplot()
plot(K_contour, contour, xaxis = ("K", (0, 8)),
     ylabel = "L", ylims=(0,8), yguidefontrotation=-90,
     label = "",)
```